# Create columns based on key and value from the same column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a lot of data in one column which contains key and value, like the data frame below:

The structure of my data is always the same, just the number of rows changes based on new movement.

```
lis = ['Date',
  '01/07/2022',
  'Location',
  'Paris',
  'Description',
  'Empty',
  'Voyage',
  'EMPTY',
  'Date',
  '28/06/2022',
  'Location',
  'Lyon',
  'Description',
  'Import',
  'Voyage',
  'LADEN',
  'Date',
  '24/06/2022',
  'Location',
  'Marseille',
  'Description',
  'PORT',
  'Voyage',
  'BARGE']
df = pd.DataFrame(lis, columns =['KEY_VAL'])
df
```

Output:

```
    KEY_VAL
0   Date
1   01/07/2022
2   Location
3   Paris
4   Description
5   Empty
6   Voyage
7   EMPTY
8   Date
9   28/06/2022
10  Location
11  Lyon
12  Description
13  Import
14  Voyage
15  LADEN
16  Date
17  24/06/2022
18  Location
19  Marseille
20  Description
21  PORT
22  Voyage
23  BARGE
```

And I want to have this output:

```
dic =   {'Date' : ['01/07/2022', '28/06/2022', '24/06/2022'], 
  'Location' : ['Paris', 'Lyon', 'Marseille'],
  'Description' : ['Empty', 'Import', 'PORT',],
  'Voyage' : ['EMPTY', 'LADEN', 'BARGE']
  }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(dic)
df2
```

Output:

```
    Date        Location    Description Voyage
0   01/07/2022  Paris       Empty       EMPTY
1   28/06/2022  Lyon        Import      LADEN
2   24/06/2022  Marseille   PORT        BARGE
```

Do you have any idea how can do this automaticly with pandas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can reshape and use a `pivot`:

```
out = (pd.DataFrame({'col': df['KEY_VAL'].to_numpy()[::2],
               'value': df['KEY_VAL'].to_numpy()[1::2]})
   .assign(idx=lambda d: d['col'].eq('Date').cumsum())
   .pivot('idx', 'col', 'value')
   .rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

Or with a Series:

```
idx = df['KEY_VAL'].to_numpy()[::2]
out = (pd.Series(df['KEY_VAL'].to_numpy()[1::2],
           index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([idx, (idx=='Date').cumsum()]))
   .unstack(0)
)
```

output:

```
         Date Description   Location Voyage
1  01/07/2022       Empty      Paris  EMPTY
2  28/06/2022      Import       Lyon  LADEN
3  24/06/2022        PORT  Marseille  BARGE
```